# How to display next and prev pagination links with WP_User_Query?

Tags: pagination, wp-user-query

Looking through the [pagination functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) available in WordPress, most seem to be associated with *posts*. [paginate_links()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) seems to be the only function which will work with `WP_User_Query`. However, when I use that I get numbered pagination:

```
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'      => get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '%_%',
    'current'   => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'format'    => 'page/%#%/',
    'prev_next' => true,
    'total'     => intval( $wp_user_query->total_users / $number ) + 1
) );
```

How can I output "Prev" and "Next" pagination links that work with `WP_User_Query`? Note, I don't want to output numbered links such as 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any generic helper - all the post-related navigation functions seem to be tied into the global `WP_Query` instance. The only real useful function at your disposal is [`get_pagenum_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pagenum_link/):

```
$paged = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );

if ( $number * $paged < $wp_user_query->total_users ) {
    printf( '<a href="%s">Next</a>', get_pagenum_link( $paged + 1 ) ); 
}

if ( $paged > 1 ) {
    printf( '<a href="%s">Back</a>', get_pagenum_link( $paged - 1 ) ); 
}
```

Note the function returns escaped strings by default, so no need for `esc_url`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had an idea there wasn't something already pre-made.